# Serialize json before returning from asp.net WebMethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

In my ASPX page, I have a WebMethod which returns a class object to a JQuery ajax request. This is my code, and it's perfectly wroking. But, I have a doubt if I need to parse it before returning object back from WebMethod (the commented code). What's the best practice ?

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static clsEntityContacts Test(string contactID, string entityID)
    { 
         clsEntityContacts result = new clsEntityContacts();
         result.contactID = "123";
         result.entityID = "12"; 
         //System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
         //JavaScriptSerializer jse = new JavaScriptSerializer();
         //jse.Serialize(result, sb);
         //return sb.ToString(); 
         return result;
    }
```

This is JQuery ajax request

```
              $.ajax({
                      url: "Entities.aspx/Test",
                      data: '{contactID:1, entityID:1}',
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/json", 
                      success: function (data) { 
                      alert(data.d.contactID );
                      },
                       error: function (data) {
                           alert('error!');
                       }
                  });
```

Comment: You don't need to do the serialization yourself, your code is fine, take a look at this [article](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/)

Comment: Why do you want to parse it? It should work the way you have written.